# Checking if a string belongs to enum as a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 model where there's

```
enum status: [:st1, :st2, :st3]
```

I want to set its status by using a **string or symbol.** How can I make sure that a string belongs to the list of values that `status` can have?

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I make sure"? What have you tried so far, if anything? (And if so, what behaviour do you get?) What behaviour do you want? As others pointed out, *Rails won't let you* set the status to something not on the list - so I'm not entirely clear what your question is.

Comment: It's worth noting that enforcing enums in the model doesn't, in fact, enforce them on a database level. And can lead to some precarious situations when migrating data in the future. Here be dragons.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a method like Marek's to check that the key is valid before updating:

```
def self.validate_status(some_status)
  ModelName.statuses.keys.include?(some_status.to_sym)
end
```

or you can rescue `ArgumentError` from your `ApiController` (if you're doing an API) with something like:

```
rescue_from ArgumentError, with: :render_status_error

def render_status_error(exception)
  logger.info(exception)
  render json: { error: 'Invalid status' }, status: :bad_request
end
```

Comment: For me under Rails 5.2.3 keys seem to be strings not symbols so  

```ModelName.statuses.keys.include?(some_status.to_s)```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how it works by default. If you try to assign something else an exception is raised

```
ArgumentError: <value> is not a valid <your_enum>
```